# Solr search in multiple tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I've three tables say brands,sites and item categories. I want to perform search functionality  in all the three tables simultaneosly. I've used solr to perform searching. Previously I was doing search one at a time. That means if the user enters 'adidas' then I was searching in brands table if didn't get then I was searching in sites table and so on. Based on the obtained results I was searching in some other table say main_nav_url using that brand_id or site_id or category_id and getting the required columns from main_nav_url table. Later on I came across this conflict like if the 'adidas' name is present in both brands and sites table I was getting only the search results of brands.

Please help me to solve this issue where I can search in all the three tables simultaneously,based on the result obtained extract their brand-id and site_id category_id, and perform One more search in main_nav_url table.

Comment: hello are see "Ransack gem " search gem it help to search data with multipale table at time using "Advance search query". please see tutorial on rails cast : 370.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Perform solr search separately to retreive their brand_id,site_id and category_id. Store the corresponding ids in an array. For example

```
@storesearch.results.each do |result|
    siteids << result.id
end
```

Depending on the length of brandids,siteids,catids perform the solr search in main_nav_url table. In this case have to perform solr search for 9 different cases. 1 of the cases is shown below.

if(siteids.length == 0 && brandids.length != 0 && catids.length != 0)
    @searchresults=MainNavigationUrl.search do
        any_of do
          with :brand_id, brandids[0..brandids.length]
          with :main_category_id, catids[0..catids.length]
        end
    end